# Make liferay portlet non instanceable

Tags: liferay, portlet

How can I make my portlet non instanceable accross the liferay instance. I have read about it in the forum but there was no mention of how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify a portlet as non instanceable by putting

```
<liferay-portlet-app>
    ...
    <portlet>
        ...
        <instanceable>false</instanceable>
        ...
    </portlet>
    ...
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

in the file 
liferay-portlet.xml

Beware of the right order of tags, according to the [dtd](http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_5_2_0.dtd) (linked the dtd version 5.2, shouldn't have changed much though)

Also have a look here
[Liferay docu](http://content.liferay.com/4.3/doc/devel/liferay_4_portlet_development_guide/multipage/ch02.html)